# How to change action bar's title by clicking a button?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm a beginner at programming in Android Studio and I'm developing a simple app for a school project. I'm using a "Maps Activity" layout and I added an action bar. I've also added some buttons, and I want to understand how to change the title on the action bar when I click a button.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via following code

```
getActionBar().setTitle("title");
```

write this line of code in action listener of the button.

Answer (score 0):

you need this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 getActionBar().setTitle(title);
                }
        });

          }

}
```